# Changing a list to a drop down and making options click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I have a site that I'm building responsive.

On one page there is a list of items. When one clicks on one of the items, it opens a panel using jQuery to show an image. Here's my HTML:

```
<h2>See the options</h2>
    <ul class="list">
        <li id="click_item1">List Item 1</li>
        <li id="click_item2">List Item 2</li>
    </ul>
```

...and jQuery code that makes that work:

```
    jQuery('#click_item1').click(function()
 {
    jQuery(".togglepanel:visible").hide();
    jQuery("#panel_item1").fadeIn();
});

jQuery('#click_item2').click(function()
 {
    jQuery(".togglepanel:visible").hide();
    jQuery("#panel_item2").fadeIn();
});
```

See a working example and code here: http://jsfiddle.net/5B8s5/1/

When the site is viewed on a smaller screen, I want to change the list to a dropdown. That part is easy. The problem is: How do I get the items in the dropdown to behave like a list of links for the benefit of jQuery so that when an item is selected from the dropdown, it triggers the correct panel to load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dropdown looks like this:

```
<select id="items">
    <option id="option_item1">Item 1</option>
    <option id="option_item2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

You'll want to handle the "change" event of your dropdown:

```
jQuery("#items").change(function() {
    var item = jQuery("#items option:selected");
    jQuery(".togglepanel:visible").hide();
    jQuery("#" + item.attr("id").replace("option", "panel")).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: That didn't work exactly as written. I changed the third line of the function to the way it was previously jQuery("#panel_item1").fadeIn(); and it works perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Comment: DOH! Spoke too soon! If I do what I wrote above, it only selects the same one every time.